# loading fact table using pentaho data integation

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I am using pentaho DI to insert data into fact table . Thing is the table from which I am populating my fact table contains 10000 reccords and changes frequently . Using database lookups and insert update I am able to load my fact table correctly once . But when new records are added to my souce table(say it becomes 15000) and I am again inserting records into fact table then these 15000 recods are again added to my fact table . What I want is to add new 5000 records that do not exist in fact table .Please suggest me on what transformations I need to perform to acheive this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try doing an upsertion instead insertion (if the row exists then update , if not insert)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some DB function.

In SQL Server 2008, there is a **merge** sql that solve this type problem.

It is a example as follows in SQL Server 2008:

`MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target
    USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
    ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Name = source.Name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

        INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
        VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)
        OUTPUT deleted., $action, inserted. INTO #MyTempTable;`